# netsh wlan command for setting wifi on laptop not working

Tags: wifi, netsh

I am converting my latop to a wifi hotspot I tried as shown in image

[image]

Need help what am I doing wrong? My mobile is not having any internet access?

Answer (score 0):

I had once used my laptop as Wifi hotspot by creating a network using the `wlan` command and then sharing my regular wired internet connection to this network.
You can get the step-by-step instructions from [this](http://www.talkofweb.com/creating-wi-fi-hotspot-in-windows-8-share-laptop-internet-connection/) link.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:** I think, problem is your driver or your command.

**Soluntion:**
You can do step over step:

1. **Check drivers**

   ```
   netsh wlan show drivers
   ```
2. **Create wifi**

   `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=wifi-windows key=12345678`
3. **Start wifi**

   `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
4. **Stop wifi**

   `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork`
5. **Delete**

   `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow ssid=wifi-windows key=12345678`

Then you can create shortcut.
To have visual image, watch on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhBn0TOkd8c&index=1&list=PLfuUuaDkOqwfCD4pwuDuzJARi_K-j71it).